# Pass object with angularJs variable value to filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-translate

I know this has cropped up a few times on here but I really can't find a suitable answer! i'm using angular-translate in a project, and I want to use the filter to pass an object with a  variable value to the back-end.

Here's how I'm implementing the use of the translate filter:

`{{ 'BUTTON_BUY' | translate: { RES: product.images.length } }}`

I have tried wrapping the object in double quotes `{{ 'BUTTON_BUY' | translate: "{ RES: product.images.length }" }}`, and I also tried escaping quotes but that doesn't work either. I have tried passing just RES: 1 and RES: 2 to check my translations pluralise properly and they do, so that leads me to believe that the issue lies in the way I am using the filter.

This is all inside an `ng-repeat` (`product` being an object in said repeated array).

Am I doing something really obviously wrong here?

Comment: Will you please provide filter code??

Comment: We're using the angular-translate module (https://angular-translate.github.io/) and ngMessageFormat (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMessageFormat) so I can't get the code for the filter. If I manually pass a string value it works as I expect, the issue occurs when I need to get that value from a variable.

Comment: Try like this  {{'BUTTON_BUY' | translate:'{ type: "raw" }' }}.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out, we didn't actually have the required data. I can, however, confirm that the following works:

`{{ 'BUTTON_BUY' | translate: { RES: product.imgQuantity } }}`

where RES is the name of the property in your JSON / Resx. For example, we went for the resx route in MVC, and this is our value:
`Choose {RES, plural, one{Picture} other{Pictures}} & Buy`.